# React Admin Add Child to Parent

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

First i have to say, i really love react-admin. Its a great package!

But my problem is the following: How can i pass properties from SelectInput to my dataprovider?

I have a SelectInput inside a ReferenceInput and a custom Add and Remove Button. This works. But i need to pass the IDs of My Parent and my child Entitiy to my dataprovider, so the correct objects can be added/removed.

Code:

```
<ReferenceInput label="Child to add" source="exercise_id" helperText="Add child to Parent" reference="exercise" filter={{type: 'ADD_CHILD'}}>
                        <SelectInput source="training" optionText="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

I tried it with filter in ReferenceInput but then the filters are only avialable trough fetching data. And not when Addind/Removing Child. The SelectInput hits the GET_MANY type out of the box.

Does anyone has good ideas?
I would be very happy about a tip or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. It's a little bit hacky, but i did it. I Created a second api handler (not the data-provider from react-admin) and created two custom react components: 
AddButton and Remove Button. 
These are used inside Create and Update Component for parent Entity. 
After the refreshView method from react-admin is called, the data is fetched newly and your added child is showing up. Wuhuu!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values in the form using the `<FormDataConsumer>` component:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#linking-two-inputs